# "name" field for Integer.class returns null

Tags: java, reflection

Class *java.lang.Class* has private field *name*. I'm trying to get value of this field for different Class instances, but when it comes to *Integer.class* the value returned is null. Here's code example:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    Class<Object> objectCls = Object.class;
    Class<Integer> integerCls = Integer.class;
    Class<Class> classCls = Class.class;
    Field nameField = classCls.getDeclaredField("name");
    nameField.setAccessible(true);
    System.out.println(nameField.get(objectCls));
    System.out.println(nameField.get(integerCls));
    System.out.println(nameField.get(classCls));
  }
}
```

Output will be:

```
java.lang.Object
null
java.lang.Class
```

Also I tried executing with online compilers that used JDK 9 and 10 and it was fine there. So problem is when I execute this code with JDK 8.

Comment: You're circumventing the class's encapsulation of that field. If you look at the source, you'll see that it's lazily initialized. So use the getter.

Comment: Why are you trying to read the private field through reflection? You could just do `integerCls.getName()`.

Comment: @ernest_k Thanks, just checked that, you're right

Comment: @Jesper I didn't know how that field was being initialized, so thought it would work

Answer (score 0):

```
instead of using private field through reflection You can just use integerCls.getName()

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
 public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
 Class<Object> objectCls = Object.class;
Class<Integer> integerCls = Integer.class;
Class<Class> classCls = Class.class;
Field nameField = classCls.getDeclaredField("name");
nameField.setAccessible(true);
System.out.println(nameField.get(objectCls));
/*System.out.println(nameField.get(integerCls));*/
System.out.println(integerCls.getName());
System.out.println(nameField.get(classCls));
```

}
}